# Adding Bootstrap class to Partial view HTML Helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'am trying to hide my partial view on extra small screens.
Because this partial is used on another wiev where it  must be visible on xs size I'm trying to hide it on Html helper method by adding one of bootstrap hidding class. 
The helper looks like this:
 @Html.Partial("_SearchBar", new {@class="hidden-xs" })
why this dont work properly ?

Comment: What does your rendered markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options:

Wrap a div around your partial

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    @Html.Partial("_SearchBar")
</div>
```

Or inside of your _SearchBar partial view add a div with the class "hidden-xs"

Comment: thanks! I prefer first option, it works like a charm . got any idea why I can't  add a class to partial ? this is out of convention ?

Comment: The @Html.Partial doesn't generate any DOM elements, it only renders what is in your partial view, so there isn't an HTML element to add the class to.